# Error OJS users and roles error "The current role does not have access to this operation"

Tags: ojs

within OJS when I try to admin the users and roles I got the alert `"The current role does not have access to this operation."` I'm not able to make changes or update modules.

I'm logged with the admin user, the version is `OJS 3.2.14`

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, there seems to be an ip check that doesn't allow one login.

1. Login into the cpanel
2. Within your website directory
3. Locate 'config.inc.php'
4. Edit this file, locate 'session_check_ip'; this was on line 256 or just search for it
5. Change this to 'Off'